# Zend_Form_Decorator - How to add attrib to Zend_Form_Element_Hidden?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

I have 2 requirements:
1) All hidden input elements should be affected without removing standard decorators.
2) This should happen WITHOUT having to specify it on a per-element basis.

All I need is for a CSS class to be attached to the DT & DD tags IF the element type is Zend_Form_Element_Hidden.

I've tried creating custom HtmlTag, DtDdWrapper, and FormElement decorators, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

By default they appear this way:

```
<dt>&nbsp;</dt>
<dd><input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="bling" /></dd>
```

I would like them to appear this way:

```
<dt class="hidden">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd class="hidden"><input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="bling" /></dd>
```

That way they'll still be where they should be, but they won't interrupt the flow of the document.

Example of what didn't work:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper extends Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        if ($this->getElement() instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Hidden)
        {
            return '<dt class="hidden">&nbsp;</dt><dd class="hidden">'.$content.'</dd>';
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($content);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your desired sample output I'm unclear why you would want to include the `<dt>` on hidden elements, especially since you're not applying any label, they end up becoming needless markup.  Following the assumption that the label *is unnecessary*, you can achieve the desired effect with the following:

```
class TestForm extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_hiddenElementDecorator = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'hidden')),
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('hidden', 'hiddenElement0');

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('hiddenElement1');
        $this->addElement($element);

    }

    public function loadDefaultDecorators()
    {
        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
            if ($element->getType() === "Zend_Form_Element_Hidden") {
                $element->setDecorators($this->_hiddenElementDecorator);
            }
        }

        parent::loadDefaultDecorators();
    }
}
```

Both of the above elements will result in the same output with their respective id's. Example:

```
<dd class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenElement0" value="" id="hiddenElement0" />
</dd>
```

The `foreach` loop in the `loadDefaultDecorators()` method iteratively applies `$this->_hiddenElementDecorator` to each hidden form element when the form is built.  If you want to apply the hidden element decorator on multiple forms, just create a parent class with the `$_hiddenElementDecorator` variable and `loadDefaultDecorators()` method in it.

---

However, if you have your heart set on including the label element (`<dt>`) as described in your sample output and applying the 'hidden' class so you end up with:

```
<dt class="hidden">&nbsp;</dt>
<dd class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenElement0" value="" id="hiddenElement0" />
</dd>
```

... you will need to extend the `Zend_Form_Decorator_Label` class and override the render() method. Take a look at the comment in the `if (null !== $tag)` block:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_Label extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Label
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $view    = $element->getView();
        if (null === $view) {
            return $content;
        }

        $label     = $this->getLabel();
        $separator = $this->getSeparator();
        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $tag       = $this->getTag();
        $id        = $this->getId();
        $class     = $this->getClass();
        $options   = $this->getOptions();

        if (empty($label) && empty($tag)) {
            return $content;
        }

        if (!empty($label)) {
            $options['class'] = $class;
            $label = $view->formLabel($element->getFullyQualifiedName(), trim($label), $options);
        } else {
            $label = '&nbsp;';
        }

        if (null !== $tag) {
            require_once 'Zend/Form/Decorator/HtmlTag.php';
            $decorator = new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag();
            // Add 'class' => 'hidden' to the <dt> tag decorator options.
            $decorator->setOptions(array('tag' => $tag, 'class' => 'hidden'));
            $label = $decorator->render($label);
        }

        switch ($placement) {
            case self::APPEND:
                return $content . $separator . $label;
            case self::PREPEND:
                return $label . $separator . $content;
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, to apply your new decorator to all of the hidden form elements you will need to add the an element prefix path point to your decorator and *re-add* the label decorator to the `$_hiddenElementDecorator` array in the `TestForm` class:

```
class TestForm extends Zend_Form
{
    protected $_hiddenElementDecorator = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'hidden')),
        // Add back the label element.
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => 'hidden')),
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addElement('hidden', 'hiddenElement0');

        $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('hiddenElement1');
        $this->addElement($element);

    }

    public function loadDefaultDecorators()
    {
        foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
            if ($element->getType() === "Zend_Form_Element_Hidden") {
                $element->setDecorators($this->_hiddenElementDecorator);
            }
        }

        // Add a decorator prefix path pointing to our new nifty decorator.
        $this->addElementPrefixPath('My_Form_Decorator', '/path/to/Decorator', Zend_Form_Element::DECORATOR);
        parent::loadDefaultDecorators();
    }
}
```

Easy as pie, no?

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman! I salute you, and make a toast to your honour!

Comment: D'oh. It's not working for me :( $this->getElements() is returning an empty array :-| There are definitely elements in the form, though!

Answer (score 0):

This will help you : 
You may also specify any other attributes.

```
$el = $form->getElement('whatever');
$el->addDecorators(
            array('ViewHelper',
            array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dt','class'=>'hidden')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'dd ',  'class'=>'hidden')),
            ));
```

Comment: I saw that in the documentation, but it meets neither of my two requirements :( Thanks for trying, though.