# HTML form with Zend Form filters/validators

Tags: html, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm creating a simple contact form within my ZF application. It doesn't feel like it's worth the trouble to manipulate decorators for only a few form elements.

My Question is: am I able to still use Zend Form Filters on elements that are *not* created with Zend Form:

### For Example:

#### The Form:

```
<!-- Standard HTML - not generated with ZF -->
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="/contact/submit">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

#### The Controller:

```
public function submitAction()
{
    $params = $this->_request->getParams();
    //Am I able to apply filters/validators to the data I get from the request?
    //What is the best way to handle this?
}
```

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534870/zend-form-how-do-i-make-it-bend-to-my-will) (the answer from Darcy Hastings) - and it seems like it would work, it just feels a bit hacky.

Any and all advice appreciated.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: I agree, I don't really like the Darcy Hastings Answer either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can use [Zend_Filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html), here is an example of how to set it up.

```
       //set filters and validators for Zend_Filter_Input
        $filters = array(
            'trackid' => array('HtmlEntities', 'StripTags')
        );

        $validators = array(
            'trackid' => array('NotEmpty', 'Int')
        );

        //assign Input
        $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators);
        $input->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());

            //check input is valid and is specifically posted as 'Delete Selected'
            if ($input->isValid()) {
```

also you may consider using the viewscript decorator to render a Zend Form, The control is absolute (or almost).:

```
//in your controller action
public function indexAction() {
        //a normally constructed Zend_Form
        $form = new Member_Form_Bid();
        $form->setAction('/member/bid/preference');
        //attach a partial to display the form, this is the decrator
        $form->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '_bidForm.phtml'))
        ));
  $this->view->form = $form;

//the view
<?php echo $this->form?>

//the partial
//use a normal Zend_Form and display only the parts you want
//processing in an action is done like any other Zend_Form
form action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction() ?>"
      method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod() ?>">
    <table id="sort">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Sort By Shift</th>
            <th colspan="2">Sort By Days Off</th>
            <th colspan="2">Sort By Bid Location</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><?php echo $this->element->shift->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td class="element"><?php echo $this->element->shift->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
            <td class="label"><?php echo $this->element->weekend->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td class="element"><?php echo $this->element->weekend->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
            <td class="label"><?php echo $this->element->bidlocation->renderLabel() ?></td>
            <td class="element"><?php echo $this->element->bidlocation->renderViewHelper() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" style="text-align: center"><?php echo $this->element->submit ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>   
</form>
```

Comment: Is there something you have to do here with `addPrefixPath` ? Getting  this error `Plugin by name 'Email' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Form_Element_: Zend/Form/Element/` and based on my searches this is the only thing I'm gathering.

Comment: Nvm, it's because I don't have an element of type Email in Zend/Form/Element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely can use `Zend_Form` on self-rendered forms.

You can do this in two ways:

1. Use a `Zend_Form` object, but don't render it. You create a `Zend_Form` instance as usual, with all the elements named correctly and attach validators and filters as per normal. In your action, you can then check the form's `isValid()` and use `getValues()` to ensure that you collect the filtered data.
2. The second option is to use `Zend_Filter_Input` which is a chain of validators and filters. You set up your validators and filters at construction and then call `setData` to populate the filter with the information from the request. Again, you have `isValid()` to test and then you use `getUnescaped()` to retrieve the data. The [manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) has more details.